# Search and modify certain strings in folder and subfolders with certain conditions with Powershell

Tags: string, powershell, expression, rename

i allready have a code that does serval things i want, but not everything i want.
I would be glad if someone could help me to complete the code to my prefs :)

What i already have, is a code that searches the folder were i startet the terminal for any string (X) and changes it to something else (A). it looks like that:

```
gci * | % { rni $_ $_.name.replace("X", "A") }
```

In a real environment the filenames look like that:

**wbm-543902-297x210-7734-lay04-02.indd**

What i want now is, change "lay" to "v" and delete the remaining text after "04".

So the result would look like this:

**wbm-543902-297x210-7734-v04.indd**

The digits vary everytime.

Finally it also would be great if i could include all subfolders to.

Thanks for your attention! :)

I tried different things i got from Chatgpt but almost nothing worked.
Also some different things with regular expressions.

Comment: "Also some different things with regular expressions." Regex does indeed sound like a good choice for this task. What did you try and how was the result?

Comment: I tried something like "(lay\d{2}*.)" , "v$*." at the end. (or allmost like that, im not shure anymore) i was so frustrated about that problem and chatgpt, so i deleted the chat from it :(

Comment: Does everything after `lay` until the `.` need to be replaced? `-replace 'lay\d{2}.*\.','lav.'`

Comment: I found a solution:
```gci * | % { rni $_ "$($_.BaseName -replace 'lay(\d{2})-(\d{2}).*', 'v$1')$($_.Extension)" }```

It does what i wanted above. But i dont know what means what.
Can anyone explain it to me in detail pls?

Comment: Ah okay thanks, so i need to remove one of the (\d{2}) right?

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the previous comment that was wrong. What happens when you use the code?

Comment: Same what is written above in ***bold txt*** :) but i didnt tried it with 3 digits, because it will never happen :)

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
# sets the regex pattern
$Pattern = 'lay([^-]*)([^\.]*)'

# Gets exclusively the files of not just $Directory, but in all its subdirectories as well
# NOTE: evaluate adding the -Filter parameter to improve efficiency if this is going to take a lot of time
$Directory | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | 
    # filters by keeping only the files matching the regex
    Where-Object { $_ -match $Pattern } | 
    # for each of those files, renames it with the -Replace function.
    ForEach-Object { Rename-Item -Path $_ -NewName ($_.Name -replace $Pattern, 'v$1' ) }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your invested time :)
I like this one, but i cant use it in powershell. How do i use this in powershell? 
I tried to reduce it to one line but that didnt work :(

Comment: @FlorianMeyer what kind of issue are you having in using it in powershell? that said, have it as One-Liner: `$Pattern = 'lay([^-]*)([^\.]*)'; $Directory | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | Where-Object { $_ -match $Pattern } | ForEach-Object { Rename-Item -Path $_ -NewName ($_.Name -replace $Pattern, 'v$1' ) }`

Answer (score 0):

This website is your best friend: https://regex101.com/

You're on the right track, remember to not use the shorten names of cmdlets it will cause confusion later on trying to remember what the command is.

- Use `Rename-Item` like this: `Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace 'lay(\d{2}).*', 'v$1' }` this will replace "lay" and the two digits after it with "v" then it removes everything after that up to the file extension.
- When doing operations like this, use the `-WhatIf` parameter to see what *would* happen if you ran this command to confirm its doing what you want.

Here's the full command in a one-liner:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Name -match 'lay\d{2}' } | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace 'lay(\d{2}).*', 'v$1' }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time Martin. It does almost what ist should, but it dont leave the fileextension :)